# What tenses is "I have a few questions"?

Tags: tense, verbs, present-perfect

> I have a few questions regarding the S22 ultra.

*have* is perfect tense, my question is in this sentence which is the verb?

Because *have* in this sentence indicates he has a question when he informs it, that's why I think this is the perfect tense, but correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Why do you think *have* means the perfect tense here?  Consider the sentence "I have a coat."  Do you think *have* is the perfect tense there?

Comment: because have in this sentence indicates he has a question when he informs it, that's why I think this is the perfect tense. but cmiiw

Comment: Please check a good dictionary for meanings of **have**. it doesn't just indicate perfect tense. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have

Comment: You need to look up present perfect tense.

Answer (score 10):

This is the simple present tense.  The word "have" is used to form perfect tenses, but it isn't being used like that here.

The perfect tenses are always formed as "have + past participle".  If there is no past participle then it isn't perfect tense.

**Have is the verb**. It is also used to show possession: "I have an apple."  And that sense is being used here.  The speaker "possesses" a few questions (in his/her head).

Comment: I don't entirely agree with your second paragraph; the past participle is often omitted when it can be understood from context. Consider, for example, "You haven't been there, **have** you?" "Yes, I **have**!"

Answer (score 3):

This is the simple present tense.

> I **have** a few questions.

In this sentence, **have** is the main/principal verb.

> I **have seen** a tiger.

In this sentence, 'seen' is the main/principal verb and 'have' is the auxiliary verb. And the sentence is in the present perfect tense.

simple present tense - base form of the verb

> I write, I play, I dance, I have,

present perfect tense- have + past participle

> I have *written*, I have *played*, I have *danced*, I have *had* etc.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Thanks a lot.